# Angular Validator.pattern() does not give same results as online regex engines

Tags: angular, regex

I have a form group. And a regular expression to validate name.
The constraints for the name input field are

- required.
- is alphanumeric.
- starts with alphabets.
- does not contain any special characters.

My regex(`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`) is working fine when checking online.
[image: regex-checking with regex101.com]
But with angular the formControl is showing valid for all strings.

Can anyone explain why is there such discrepancies between the results with angular **Validator.pattern()** and **js engine**.

I have tried the following with no avail (all are suggestions from stackoverflow answers):

- `Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/)`
- `Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*')`

```
const nameRegex='^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern(nameRegex)],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailRegex)]],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
      c_password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in the `FormGroup`. The `name` form control validators is missing brackets.

```
name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(nameRegex)]],
```